# Missing line of codes: Return to main menu or exit the program (Python)

Tags: python

We were given a problem and I missed some of the main components of the problem:

> After input and computations always ask if user wants to input another, if not, ask to return to main menu or exit the program entirely.

> At the main menu, if the user chooses to Exit, ask if he/sure to exit

To remove my confusion, what line of codes do I need to include for the program to ask if you want to return or exit the program and ask again if he/she is sure?

```
CHOICE = 0
HW = 0
HR = 0
GP = 0
IT = 0
RD = 0
SSS = 0
TD = 0
OT = 0

AYAW = True
while AYAW:
print("*" * 100)
print(" " * 100)
print(" " * 40 + "PAYROLL SYSTEM MENU" + " " * 35)

print(" " * 35 + "[1] Employee Data Input" + " " * 35)
print(" " * 35 + "[2] Employee Grosspay Computation" + " " * 35)
print(" " * 35 + "[3] Employee Deduction Computation" + " " * 35)
print(" " * 35 + "[4] Employee Netpay Computation" + " " * 35)
print(" " * 35 + "[5] Exit" + " " * 35)

#CHOICE
CHOICE = input(" " * 40 + "CHOICE ===> ")
print(" " * 100)
print("*" * 100)

#Employee Data Input
if (CHOICE == "1"):
    input("Employee Name (Last Name, First Name, Middle Initial: ")
    int(input("Employee Number: "))
    input("Department (Marketing/Production/Logistics/Packaging/Purchasing/Admin): ")
    input("Status (Permanent/Probationary/Contractual): ")
    HW = int(input("Employee's Rate per hour: "))
    HR = int(input("Employee's Hours Worked: "))

#Grosspay

GP = HW * HR
if (CHOICE == "2"):
    print("Grosspay:" ,GP)

#Deduction

if (CHOICE == "3"):
    IT = 0

    if (GP > 40000):
        IT = GP * 0.12

    if (GP < 1500):
        RD = GP * 0.01
    else:
        RD = GP * 0.02

        SSS = GP * 0.045

        TD = IT + RD + SSS
    print("Total Deductions", TD)

#Netpay

if (CHOICE == "4"):
    OT = 0
    if (HW > 40):
        OT = GP * 0.015 

    NP = (GP + OT) - TD 
    print("Netpay", NP)

#End the program

if (CHOICE == "5"):
    AYAW = False
    print("Done!")
```

Comment: Pleas fix all indentation. welcome to SO - take the [tour] and read through [ask], [mre] and other links found in the [help].

Answer (score 0):

- Encapsulate the process in a function
- In a loop:

  - Call the function
  - Ask the user to make a/some decision(s)
  - If user desires to quit exit the loop

Comment: You might want to split the process into more than one function.